# Inserting into a simple Array and Deleting

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, stack, queue

```
public class DataOperations {
int arraySize=50;
int[]array=new int[arraySize];
public void generateRandomArray(){
for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++){
    array[i]=i;


}
}
public int getValueAtIndex(int index){
if(index<arraySize){
    System.out.println("Your value At index "+index+" is "+array[index]);
    return array[index];
}else{
    System.out.println("Please Return an Index that is inbounds");
    return 0;
}
}
public boolean doesArrayContainValue(int searchValue){
boolean valueInArray=false;
for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++){
    if(array[i]==searchValue){
         valueInArray=true;
    }
}
return valueInArray;

}
 public void deleteIndex(int index){
if(index<arraySize){
    for(int i=index;i<(arraySize-1);i++){
        array[i]=array[i+1];

    }       
}
System.out.println(arraySize);
arraySize--;
System.out.println(arraySize);


}
public void printArray(){
for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++){
    System.out.print(i+"-");
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
}
public void insertValue(int index){
if(index<arraySize){
array[arraySize]=index;
System.out.println(arraySize);
arraySize++;
System.out.println(arraySize);
}

}
 public void linearSearchForValue(int value){
boolean valueInArray=false;
System.out.println("The was Found and is at Index:");
for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++){
    if(array[i]==value){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}
}
```

Hey So I created simple add and delete methods to my array. However, I am unsure about a couple parts. I Understand the add method, and that we are decreasing the arraySize from 50 to 49 for this specific array object that I created in my Driver class below. However, I am not sure why I cannot do my add method before my delete method insertValue method if I put arraySize++ before array[arraySize]=index, and did not call my deleteIndex method shouldnt my arraySize=51? but this throws an out of bounds exception
Driver Class Below

```
public class Driver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataOperations array=new DataOperations();
    array.generateRandomArray();
    array.insertValue(20);
    array.printArray();

}
}
```

Comment: Arrays are fixed size data structure. You cannot chage its size on the fly. Here in your case, arraysize is not the actual arraysize, you are maintaining it for computing purpose. Actual arraysize you would get by calling array.length. It would be constant across life of that array. If you want to change the size, use ArrayList.

Comment: But then how come this works if I call my deleteIndex method first, then I call my insert method. If it was fixed then shouldnt it not matter which method I called first? shouldnt it give me an out of bounds exception every time?

Comment: It will work as long as you size doesn't cross the actual arraysize. So as long as your size is less than 50, any number of add and delete will work. Once it reaches 50, It will start failing. You are mixing your own variable with java's array size.have a look at this one - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Oh wait so I think I understand, so If I create a variable called arraySize=10; and then made my array size =50; I can insert and delete because I wont be manipulating the actual array size right?

Comment: if you create an array of size 10, and you want to insert 50 elements, you will have to create new array of size 50, copy the elements from array of size 10, then add the remaining elements. You cannot modify the old array to a new size.

Comment: Given this statement, it will not work "int[]array=new int[arraySize];" You are creating array of arraysize.

Comment: but if I do arraySize=10; and int[]array=new int[50]; it should right

Comment: You are better off using an ArrayList<Integer> and using it's add and remove methods.

Answer (score 0):

`int arraySize=50;`

You create an array of size 50. Arrays are of fixed size hence you cannot get an array of size 51. In your code, when adding/deleting an element from the array, you arent changing the size of the array. You are just moving the index to get your desired output. If you want a bigger array you can:

1. Create a new array of required size and copy all elements from old to new
2. Use ArrayList instead of arrays.

Comment: if you create an array of size 10, and you want to insert 50 elements, you will have to create new array of size 50, copy the elements from array of size 10, then add the remaining elements. You cannot modify the old array to a new size.